# Bellman-Ford algorithm trace

Tags: algorithm, trace, directed-graph, edges, bellman-ford

I don't know where else to post this question, I just want to know if I did this trace correctly. I am given this diagram

[image: diagram]

and here is the question:

> Show the trace of the Bellman-Ford algorithm on the following directed graph, using vertex t as the source. In each pass, relax edges in the order of(x, t),(y, z),(u, t),(y, x),(u, y),(t, x),(t, y), (t, z),(z, x),(z, u). Show the d values after each pass. Does the graph have negatively weighted circles? How do you examine it by using the Bellman-Ford algorithm?

The answer I got was u=12, t=0, x=4, y=12, and z=-3, and it doesn't have a negative weighted circle. This question is worth a lot of points and one mistake means minus a lot, so I don't know who else to have to check this for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relaxing in the order you specified -
Initially the d values are `<t = 0, u = inf, x = inf, y = inf, z = inf>`

```
(x, t) <0, inf, inf, inf, inf>  
(y, z) <0, inf, inf, inf, inf>   
(u, t) <0, inf, inf, inf, inf>   
(y, x) <0, inf, inf, inf, inf>   
(u, y) <0, inf, inf, inf, inf> <--Upto this no update because no relaxation started from non-inf  
(t, x) <0, inf, 7, inf, inf>   
(t, y) <0, inf, 7, 12, inf>   
(t, z) <0, inf, 7, 12, -3>   
(z, x) <0, inf, 4, 12, -3>   
(z, u) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>
```

Second iteration

```
(x, t) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>  
(y, z) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(u, t) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(y, x) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(u, y) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>  
(t, x) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(t, y) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(t, z) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(z, x) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>   
(z, u) <0, 12, 4, 12, -3>
```

Since it didn't change after second iteration, this is the final answer, which matched yours.
Also there is no negative weight cycle, because of no change in entire iteration.

Note - Had the order of edges, been different, we might have expected change in second iteration.

Comment: thank you, I was just making sure I wasn't wrong because I got what you got, only after 2 iterations so i thought somewhere i made a mistake. good stuff. thank you